# What is the next step after doing factor loadings in Structural Equation Modelling in Lavaan R?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I ran a CFA model.

From the research papers I've read, I realized I need to calculate t-values and find a "critical t-value". However, I don't know how to do that and in the summary table I only have z-values.

Second, does a latent variable have an $R^2$?

I ran:

```
summary(model1.fit, rsqaure=TRUE)
```

for the model but didn't get an $R^2$ value for only one of the 2 latent variables I have.

Comment: Could you provide the results you did get from the summary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z and t are interchangeable. Some software gives t, some gives z. And most give the p-value and the confidence intervals, which is what you care about. What are you trying to find out? That should inform what you report.

You only get an R-square value for a latent variable if it is endogenous - that is, if something is predicting it. (Otherwise R-square is zero).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jeremy ! Having found the factor loadings, I am trying to find whether the hypotheses tested can be confirmed or rejected, and for that I thought I needed to look at z-values. So would I have to look at z-values over 1.6449 (95% confidence) to see if my hypotheses are confirmed or not? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can't confirm a hypothesis. You can reject, or fail to reject, the null hypothesis. Which hypothesis are you talking about?